# 404 Error for the files in project folder that created in wwwroot folder While hosting the MEAN Appliation in IIS server

Tags: iis, iisnode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD83A.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rRf0.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm0lp.jpg)I'm trying to host my mean stack application in IIS server, for that I created a new project and given bindings for the folder, the application working fine with this. When I'm trying to create in default website in IIS then I got the error for the files in the project folder that is inside of my wwwroot folder. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Keep in mind that nobody can see your screen. Show screen shots please.

Comment: ok i will share

Comment: How does the set up of your IIS also with your Website creation.

Comment: Please see the images attached